# mysql show all column but certain column to be unique

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql database but I would like to filter certain column to be unique however all column need to be show

`id`, `events`, `times`, `name`, `email` and `reg_date` is the column need to show, but I need `events`, `times`, `name` and `email` to be unique so it will not be showing duplicate data

tried this but eventually it's only show the columns

```
Select distinct events, times, name, email FROM database
```

Comment: Please add sample input and output data to your question.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about this ?

```
select events, times, name, email FROM database
group by events, times, name, email
```